# Executing adb pull via Groovy results in corrupt file

Tags: android, groovy, adb

I try to execute adb pull  via a groovy file to download files automatically from the device.

```
private void getFile(String fileName) {
    def process = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO()
                     .command(adbExec, "pull", "/sdcard/some.mp4").start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

After the process is finished, unfortunately the file (mp4 from screenrecord) seems to be corrupt. If i "pull it manually" everything is fine. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: 
After cancelling the screenrecord (via script) it needs some time to save it correctly.
Screenrecord -> finished -> sleep -> pull -> works